# Once S7FTPRequest is added iPhone app does not compile

Tags: iphone, cocoa, build, ftp, compilation

New to iPhone app development, I have a problem compiling (or "Build and Run") my application after including S7FTPRequest into my class library; before I even include it in any particular script.  I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
"_kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword", referenced from:
_kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword$non_lazy_ptr in S7FTPRequest.o
(maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword$non_lazy_ptr)
"_CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL", referenced from:
-[S7FTPRequest startUploadRequest] in S7FTPRequest.o
-[S7FTPRequest startCreateDirectoryRequest] in S7FTPRequest.o
"_kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName", referenced from:
 _kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName$non_lazy_ptr in S7FTPRequest.o
 (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainFTP", referenced from:
 _kCFStreamErrorDomainFTP$non_lazy_ptr in S7FTPRequest.o
 (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamErrorDomainFTP$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I kinda gave up on this solution (for the time being) but I think I solved the issue when trying something different.

It seems that many external components need some accommodating linked libraries.

You can add new libraries by going to Project > Edit Active Target "ProjectName" > General

Then you click the plus simple to see all the available libraries.

Not sure which one fixed but I added these for a different solution and voila S7FTPRequest compiled.

Here are the libraries I added (I think it was actually libz.1.2.3.dylib):

CoreGraphics.framework
CFNetwork.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
libz.1.2.3.dylib

Comment: S7FTPRequest is now called SCRFTPRequest and located here https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest

Answer (score 2):

You got it a little wrong. The problem is coming due to linking as a required framework is missing, but the framework needed is `CFNetwork.framework` and **not** libz.1.2.3.dylib

The libz dynamic library is used for zipping/unzipping operations.